# How can I restart this code automatically?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import math
import argparse
def highlightFace(net, frame, conf_threshold=0.7):
 frameOpencvDnn = frame.copy()
 frameHeight = frameOpencvDnn.shape[0]
 frameWidth = frameOpencvDnn.shape[1]
 blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frameOpencvDnn, 1.0, (300, 300), [104, 117, 123], True, False)
 .
 .              # CODE TO DETECT FACES AND PLAY ADS
 cap.release()  # CLOSE THE FRAMES SO IT CAN RESTART AGAIN
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code above creates 2 new frames, one shows the detected  face and the other one plays the ads. The aim is to restart the code again to detect a different face.

Comment: Call it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function again at the end of the function:

```
import time
def highlightFace(net, frame, conf_threshold=0.7):
    ...
    YOUR CODE HERE
    ...
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    time.sleep(1)  # Allow some time for KeyBoardInterrupt
    highlightFace(net, frame, conf_threshold=0.7) # Call the function again at the end
```